# Unable to load a js framework while the authors demo works without problems

Tags: javascript, formio

I'm trying to use `formio` and a 3-rd party framework `formio-export` but I'm having trouble getting started.

The author provided a sample of the framework on his [github page](https://github.com/airarrazaval/formio-export). Demo can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/formio-export).

I've tried to recreate a simple demo using HTML/JS. 
I was able to create the form, load a submission on demand, but I'm unable to get the print functionality working. When I press the print button, I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: FormioExport is not defined
>   at HTMLButtonElement. (:47:21)
>   at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (index.js:3)
>   at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (index.js:3)

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jhv73b1/2/) for your convenience.

I would expect the `formio-export` to 'just work' once the `script` tag is added but maybe it requires some additonal configs?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it in the browser directly. You must use node in order to import the module

```
import FormioExport from 'formio-export';
```

and then use

```
npm run build
```

to make a browser bundle (as explained in the github page).

Comment: The `js` file I'm referencing is the built `formio-export.js` file, not the source file.